# Deselect a radio button in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Is there a way to use the qualtrics javascript api (or, if not, a workaround) to programatically clear all entries made to radio buttons on a page?

My usage case is in a matrix table question that "pipes" (actually uses embedded data) values from the previous question to puts calculated numbers into the statements. However, if the respondent navigates back then when the return to the following question the numbers have changed but the responses have remained. As such, if it is the second time a respondent is viewing a page constructed like this, I want to clear all their previous answers.

I want to make sure that qualtrics' data is updated properly.

My survey is currently using the JFE engine if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes there is a way with JavaScript, but with JFE it is quite complicated.  It is quite easy in SE (you need to do it for both, because while you can force SE only, you can't force JFE only).  A much easier solution would be to just hide the Previous Button on the next page.

Answer (score -1):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var QID = this.questionId;
    var that = this;
    var counts = [];
    var radioButtonsClean = [];
    var radioButtons = $(QID).getElementsByTagName('input');
    var radioIndex = [];

    for(var i=0; i<radioButtons.length; i++) {
        if(radioButtons[i].type == 'radio') {
            radioButtonsClean.push(radioButtons[i]);
            radioIndex.push(radioButtons[i].id);
        }
    }

    // Set counts for each displayed radio button to 0
    for(var i=0; i<radioButtonsClean.length; i++) {
        counts[i] = 0;
    }

    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if (element.type == 'radio')  {   
            var thisId = element.id;
            var spotCheck = radioIndex.indexOf(thisId);
            var count = counts[spotCheck];

            if (count == 0) {
                for(var i=0; i<counts.length; i++) {
                    counts[i] = 0;
                }

                counts[spotCheck] = 1;
            }
            else {
                this.setChoiceValue(element.id.split('~')[2], element.id.split('~')[3], false);
                counts[spotCheck] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code sample. Can you include a explanation to supplement your code?